# How Can I have multiples instances of a Spring boot Repository(Interface), to have a complete test-state-isolation?

Tags: spring-data, spring-webflux, autowired, junit5, spring-test

### 1) Contextualization:

- In order, to have a complete test-isolation-state in all test of my Test-Class;
- I would like to have a new-instance-repository(DAO) for each individual test;
- My Repository is a Interface, thats the why I can not simply instantiate that.

**My Goal is:**

- Run all tests 'Parallelly', meaning 'at the same time';
  [image: Parallel Tests]
- That's the why, I need individual/multiple instances of Repository(DAO) in each test;
- Those multiple instances will make sure that the tests' conclusion would not interfere on those that still is running.

*Below is the code for the above situation:*

#### 1.1) Code:

**Current working status:** working, BUT with ths SAME-REPOSITORY-INSTANCE;

**Current behaviour:**

- The tests are not stable;
- SOMETIMES, they interfere in each other;
- meaning, the test that finalize early, destroy the Repository Bean that still is being used, for the test that is still running.

```java
public class ServiceTests2 extends ConfigTests {

  private List<Customer> customerList;
  private Flux<Customer> customerFlux;

  @Lazy
  @Autowired
  private ICustomerRepo repo;
  private ICustomerService service;


  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    service = new CustomerService(repo);

    Customer customer1 = customerWithName().create();
    Customer customer2 = customerWithName().create();
    customerList = Arrays.asList(customer1,customer2);
    customerFlux = service.saveAll(customerList);
  }

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Save")
  public void save() {
    StepVerifier.create(customerFlux)
                .expectNextSequence(customerList)
                .verifyComplete();
  }


  @Test
  @DisplayName("Find: Objects")
  public void find_object() {
    StepVerifier
         .create(customerFlux)
         .expectNext(customerList.get(0))
         .expectNext(customerList.get(1))
         .verifyComplete();
  }
}
```

---

### 2) The ERROR happening:

- This ERROR happens in the failed-Tests:
  [image]

### 3) Question:

- How Can I create multiple instances of Repository

  - Even if, it being a Interface(does not allow instantation)?

    - In order, to have a COMPLETE TEST-ISOLATION

      - Meaning: ONE different instance of Repository in each test?

---

*Thanks a lot for any help or idea*

Comment: what level of testing are you doing here? (unit, integration, acceptance etc)

Comment: @MichaelMcFadyen Integration Test.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @DirtiesContext annotation on the test class that modifies the application context.

[Java Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html)

[Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-spring)

By default, this will mark the application context as dirty after the entire test class is run. If you would like to mark the context as dirty after a single test method, then you can either annotate the test method instead or set the classMode property to AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD at your class level annotation.

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

> When an application context is marked dirty, it is removed from the
> testing framework's cache and closed; thus the underlying Spring
> container is rebuilt for any subsequent test that requires a context
> with the same set of resource locations.